# CSS3 Animation is not zooming out to the center of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an animation that I am trying to zoom out so it doesn't get cut off the page.  I've tried setting position to fixed, but that doesn't work.

```
.mainstream {
height: 17em;
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
top: 53%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 34em;
}

.logo {
position: absolute;
top: -0.75em;
}

.logo {
animation: logo 8s ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
}


/* Keyframes */

@keyframes logo {
100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.3) translateY(-.75em);
}
89% {
    opacity: .7;
}
40% {
    opacity: .5;
    transform: scale(1);
}
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateZ(-1000em);
}
}


/* Make the 3D work on the container */

.mainstream {
perspective: 800px;
transform-style: preserve3d;
}
```

Here is the codepen:  https://codepen.io/enavu/pen/wrOQPj

I don't want it to cut off as in this photo:
[image]

Comment: I don't see where the animation is being cut off in your codepen...

Comment: @Mark, added a photo of what I see on my screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the logo from being cut off by setting a `max-width` on `#hideMe`. I set it to 50%, and set the parent container's `display` property to centered `flex` in order to align the animation.

This takes care of the issue with the exception of very small viewports (like the snippet preview window below). If you don't want the logo to be cut off on any screen, you could use media queries and set different max-width's for `#hideMe`.

Hope this helps!

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $("body").removeClass("preload");
});
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $("#loading").fadeOut("fast");
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hideMe').fadeOut(5000);
  $('#close').fadeIn(10000);
  $('#text').fadeIn(10000);
});
```

```css
/* Code to do animation after page load*/

.preload {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
}


/* Logo for page loading*/

.mainstreamloading {
  height: 2em;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 53%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 2em;
  opacity: .2;
}


/* Animation for M*/

.mainstream {
  height: 17em;
  left: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 53%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 34em;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.75em;
}

.logo {
  animation: logo 8s ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}


/* Keyframes */

@keyframes logo {
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.3) translateY(-.75em);
  }
  89% {
    opacity: .7;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: .5;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateZ(-1000em);
  }
}


/* Make the 3D work on the container */

.mainstream {
  perspective: 800px;
  transform-style: preserve3d;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#hideMe {
  max-width: 50%;
}

img {
  width: 90%;
}

.img-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#close {
  display: none;
}

#text {
  display: none;
}

.nav-top-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 2px;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: white;
  background-color: currentColor;
  pointer-events: none;
  height: 30px;
}

.nav-work {
  top: 25px;
  right: 50px;
}

.nav-item {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-size: 0.78571rem;
  line-height: 2.27273;
  letter-spacing: 0.11em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.link-brand-inner {
  color: white
}

.link-brand {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-about {
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.nav-about-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 2px;
  color: white;
  background-color: currentColor;
  height: 30px;
}

.mid-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}


/* General styles and layout */

body {
  background: black;
  /*url(https://i.imgur.com/3nM3maK.jpg);*/
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*** Media queries for adjusting to different screen sizes ***/

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .mainstream {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mainstream {
    font-size: 7px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>MNSTRM</title>

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/animation.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700'>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
  <img id="loading" src="https://i.imgur.com/O81HQdi.png" alt="loading" class="mainstreamloading img-circle">
</head>

<body class="preload">

  <div class="mainstream">
    <img id="hideMe" src="https://i.imgur.com/O81HQdi.png" alt="logo" class="logo img-circle">
  </div>
  <div id="close">
    <span class="nav-top-line"></span>
    <div class="nav-item nav-work">
      <span class="link-brand-inner"><font face="Lato">Gallery</font></span>
    </div>
    <div class="mid-nav">
      <div class="nav-about">
        <span class="nav-about-line"></span>
        <span class="link-brand-inner"><font face="Lato">ABOUT</font></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you but it appears to make the animation skew to the left a little.  Is there any way to just make it zoom straight to the middle of the screen vs down a little?

Comment: @epv did you add display:flex and justify-content: center to .mainstream? That code should center the logo and make it zoom down the middle.

Comment: Try adding those along with max-width:50% to #hideMe. It should perfectly center the logo as it zooms in